# Updating a div with ajax, depending on the return value of PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a form like the following.

```
<div id="loginerr"></div>
<form action="?page=login" method="POST" id="loginForm">
    <table width="224" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" style="padding-top: 45px;">
        <tr>
            <td height="26" align="center" valign="middle">
                <input tabindex="1" id="username" name="username" type="text" style="width: 157px; background-color: #e8eff7; border: 2px solid #889db0; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;"/></td>
            <td align="center" valign="middle" rowspan="2" width="57" height="52">
                    Login button --> <div id="login" class="login"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
             <td height="26" align="center" valign="middle">
                <input tabindex="2" id="password" name="password" type="password" style="width: 157px; background-color: #e8eff7; border: 2px solid #889db0; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;"/>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td height="40" colspan="2" align="center" valign="middle">
                <a><:FORGOT_PASSWORD:></a>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center" valign="middle">
                <a href="#!?page=register"><div class="signup"></div></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

This script requests ?page=login address with Username and Password and updates "loginerr" div with the returned data.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#login").click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();  // prevent normal form submit
        $("#loginerr").html('<img src="<%THEME%>images/loading.gif">');
        var formData = $("#loginForm").serialize();
        $.post("?page=login", formData, function(data)
        {
            $("#loginerr").html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

The thing I want to do is, if it returns success message (user successfully logged in) it should replace this form with account.php contents.

I tried to do it myself, but failed.

Please help.

Comment: Why not just redirect to the Account page?

Comment: Page will be reload if I do so. It shouldn't do any reloads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what was my solution (not in PHP but doesn't matter) is that my action returned either an HTML which I updated via $('#res').html(data) or a json with a href attribute, to which I was redirecting. In your case you can do exactly the same, but instead of redirection just make another AJAX call if you wish. The code in 'onSuccess'  was something like:

```
if(data.href) doAjaxCall(data.href) else $('#res').html(data)
```

hope this helps

in your code to vizualize it would be something like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#login").click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();  // prevent normal form submit
        $("#loginerr").html('<img src="<%THEME%>images/loading.gif">');
        var formData = $("#loginForm").serialize();
        $.post("?page=login", formData, function(data)
        {
            if(data.href) doAjaxCall(data.href) else $("#loginerr").html(data) // this line changed
        });
    });
});
```

Other way of handling this problem is to return different status if logging in did not work, for example 403, in that case you can check what was the response status and either update #loginrr or something else. you can also return json array with index "failed" and "succeeded" and use if(data.failed) update loginrr else if (data.succeeded) update somethingElse. There are plenty of possibilities. pick the one you like.

Comment: Returning a json array would be the best. I've already thought about this but I don't have the knowledge of writing one. Guess I'll have to search for examples.

Comment: take a look at [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). I believe what you need to do is to echo json_encode(array("ok" => "Login successful!", "wrong" => "sorry, wrong username or password"));

Comment: When I try to reach these values in my form, I should use data.ok and data.wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Their doesn't seem to be any reference above to account.php above? You are posting to?page=login ?

Comment: I post to login.php. It checks username/password with database values. If passwords doesn't match, it updates loginerr div with html value. However, if user succeeds logging in, I want whole area to be refreshed, not just the loginerr. So yeah, I will basically include account.php page and return it as a HTML. The only problem is, my current jQuery script doesn't understand if it returned the "error" value or "success" value. Need a check for it.

Comment: Ah easy. On your password validation screen either shoot back:

Comment: 2) a valid in the HTML that the JavaScript will look for if (data.indexOf('success'))

Comment: Or 3) change your login validation page to json encoded response. Echo json_encode(array('result'=>'success',data=>'HTML stuff here')):